# closed but not exact

Tags: differential-geometry

I saw several times that $\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$ is closed but not exact. Closed, is obvious but I can't prove non exactness, can one please help me ?

My attempt, let $f\in \omega^{0}(U)$ and $df=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$ and so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$. Now let $g(\theta)=f(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ so $g'(\theta)=1 \implies g(\theta)=\theta+C$. Now i'm not getting any contradiction.

Comment: Integrate the form over a circle with centre $0$.

Comment: Ok, but is there anything wrong in my attempt upto that ?

Comment: Well, the final step is missing, that $\theta$ is not well-defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, so $g$ is only locally definable, not globally. [Note that every closed form is locally exact.]

Comment: Nothing wrong with your attempt, until the final sentence. You do have a contradiction, because $\theta$ is not well defined single valued continuous function.

Comment: Ok so, can i also say like this ? $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ should be continuous but its not at $\{0,0\}$

Comment: the form you had taken is actually a closed form. So it wouldn't help the way you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

You know that if you integrate over a loop into which there is no singularity, as the form is exact the integral is 0.

Then let us try with a loop containing 0 inside: let us take the circle $C(0,1)$.

$$\int_{C(0,1)} -\frac y{x^2 + y^2}dx + \frac x{x^2 + y^2}dy
= \int_0^{2\pi}  -\frac {r\sin\theta}{r^2} (-r \sin\theta d\theta)  
+ {r\cos\theta}{r^2} (r \cos\theta d\theta)\\  = 2\pi \neq 0
$$

Comment: Ok i got it, but I've not seen yet proof of the fact that exact iff that integration over a closed curve is zero. Can you please provide a reference for that ?

Comment: then what is your definition of exact?